# Turning off Apple hardware checks on startup

Tags: startup

Since I stay on top of possible hardware errors using utilities, I don't want to allow my Mac to boot up and go through the checks each time.  How do I skip over this process each time the computer boots by using Terminal commands, and then how do I reinstate the default startup routines if I want to have a traditional boot?

Comment: The POST process takes mere seconds, and can identify problems that can have serious ramifications with disastrous complications.

Comment: How often do you shut down and start up, and/or reboot? I go for weeks, probably months, between reboots. I only reboot when there's an unrecoverable error, which is probably once or twice a year.

Comment: You're also assuming Jan that there's not been an issue since you last checked and your mac booting up, that's why you have the POST checks.

Comment: My Macbook only boots when there is a kernel update or something has gone very wrong.  Both are quite seldom.

Answer (score 7):

You can’t bypass this.

It’s technically not an Apple limitation as all computers (PCs too) need to run a minimal set of tests to probe how much RAM is available, what boot devices are present, etc.   Without it, your Mac wouldn’t know from where to boot from at a very minimum

Answer (score 5):

There is no official way to disable hardware checks when your Mac boots up.

These hardware tests are collectively referred to as the [Power On Self-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) (POST) stage. These checks are considered critical to safely and securely booting the operating system.

## Boot Arguments

You can learn more about the available boot time options through the links below:

- [Boot argument options in OS X](https://osxeon.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/boot-argument-options-in-os-x/)
- [How to View & Clear the Mac NVRAM Contents from Terminal in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2015/12/16/view-clear-nvram-mac-command-line-osx/)